camera animation - camera following path with offset
the camera has a weird offset from the path i want to follow. the origin of the camera has a blue dotted line to a weird place in the curve which i feel is the reason for offset. I shall show how i do the animation.
video of how i set animation 


the weird offset is highlighted in red and the blue shows how i want the camera to follow the path
moonboots solution worked in getting the camera to the position.
the al + g actually solved the issue however the camera has the blue line going somewhere in the world and when i change the offset from 616 to 522 it doesnt happen to be following the curve i just made.



Select the camera and press Alt G so that it sticks to the curve, does it fix the problem?

yes thanks! may i know why this is happening ?

you need to reset the camera location, Alt G, so that it sticks to the first vertx of the curve, otherwise Blender thinks that you want to offset its location

Select the camera and reset its location with AltG so that it sticks to the curve first vertex, otherwise you'll have an offset.

i did do that and it solved the issue however the camera has the blue line going somewhere in the world and when i change the offset from 616 to 522 it doesnt happen to be following the curve i just made.

i found the solution to my weird problem . apparently its important that the offset constraint of the camera is set to 0 before doing the alt + G.
